# Can you set textboxes to remember previous entries with ASP.NET 4.0?

Tags: asp.net, textbox

Website was upgraded from .NET 1.1 to .NET 4.0 and client complains that autocomplete feature of textboxes is no longer functioning.  Can this be set somehow?  Sitewide or by each control?

Comment: This is a very vague. Was the textbox an old web control that you used? Can you give more details? There is no setting for autocomplete for ASP.NET textboxes, it's a feature you either code in yourself, or use a web control to achieve for example.

Comment: They are just standard <asp:textbox> controls.  Perhaps autocomplete was the wrong word, what I was looking for was where it would remember previous entries.  I.E. you start to type user name "ad" and "admin" pops up, or you double-click in the textbox and can see a list of previous entries that the user has made.

Comment: Ahh OK. That functionality is dealt with by the browser,not ASP.NET. The browser will cache previously entered values for a input field (aka textbox). If you clear the browser cache, then those values will be wiped and you have to type in the field again for it to be cached. I'm not aware of any ASP.NET "feature" that relates to this.

Comment: After digging a little deeper, I found that you can (supposedly) modify the behavior of textboxes with the AutoCompleteType attribute on a textbox control.  It is supposed to be set to "None" by default, which counterintuitively lets autocomplete WORK for any textbox with the same ID (otherwise it only works for textboxes that match both the ID *and* category, i.e. AutoCompleteType="FirstName").  However...  though I explicitly set one of these to "DisplayName", it still will not remember the history even after clicking the submit button successfully on a form.

Comment: I checked my browser settings.  While UserNames and Passwords AutoComplete was enabled, forms was not.  (I'm curious how it knows something is a UserName rather than a general form textbox).  I enabled forms, and...  it didn't solve anything.

Comment: Browsers will pick up on the type attribute  `<input type="typeName"` and based on that can manipulate the input field. For example, notice how a password input field displays * when you type. I guess this autocomplete is a similar thing. I'm not really sure what is going here, it's a bit out of my comfort zone I'm afraid. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was an HTML attribute autocomplete="off" on the form tag.

Comment: For reference the autocomplete attribute is new to HTML5 (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input#Attributes) but is supported in older versions of Internet Explorer as it originated in that browser.